# Need to find the value of input field generated by *ngFor

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let ivalue of arraytoDispaly;let i = index;">
    <input type="text" [value]="ivalue.inputValue" />
    <button (click)='GetId(i)'>GetID</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
arraytoDispaly = [
{'inputValue':'abc'},
{'inputValue':'def'},
{'inputValue':'ghi'}];
GetId(val){
    console.log()
   }
```

Need to get the value of input field on clicking button, I have used ElementRef and @ViewChild but not getting the value. Can anyone guide what I need to do although I am getting value by id using document.getElementById but need to know the Angular way of access value, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass current value instead of index in `ngFor` like below -

```
<div *ngFor="let ivalue of arraytoDispaly;let i = index;">
    ....
<button (click)='GetId(ivalue)'>GetID</button>

GetId(val){
  console.log(val.inputValue)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Can you also tell what is the way to access the input value generated using *ngFor by id or anything from any function call apart from the function above.

Comment: apart from the above method, yes you can access the value using `id` but for that, you need to assign `id`  to element dynamically.

Comment: @MOBASHIRIQBAL If it's only one ngFor you're using for the component you can do `id={{i}}`

Comment: Thanks again, are you telling to access using document.getElementbyId or something else can you please specify

Comment: yes if you assign dynamic `id` then you can go with `document.getElementbyId`

Comment: Is there any other way apart from document.getElementbyId?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<div *ngFor="let ivalue of arraytoDispaly;let i = index;">
    <input #i type="text" [value]="ivalue.inputValue" />
    <button (click)='getId(i.value)'>GetID</button>
</div>
```

---

```
getId(val){
    console.log(val)
   }
```

**[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-1erzi2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

---

**PS:** methods should be camelcased (`getId` not `GetId`)

Comment: @PardeepJain yup, an input has a value dude

Comment: you have name the input as i and i as index 

Comment: @malbarmawi so what ?

Comment: @malbarmawi, the input is inside an ngFor dude, plz before editing, check if its working..

Comment: @PardeepJain, yes so what ?, it is the index, I know, and should be tho

Comment: even its working it wrong just check the `var a = 10; var a = 20; ` is this ok for you a now 20 but I want to display 10 , 

Comment: @selemmn your code may work fine reason is you have declared local variable with same name `i` which is already used as `index` which is not recommended, I commented because I misunderstood as you are passing only index and trying value from that. I hope this clears what I mean

Comment: @PardeepJain, could you tell me why it's not recommended ?, I dunno if u get the idea behind

Comment: @selemmn because sometimes in complex problems it gets complicated to get value of variables having same name.

Comment: @PardeepJain, well dont get ur point's relation to the current question, (since obviously it's not complex here), and it is a way of 100 to solve that problem he had + to know that he could have dynamic template references within a simple `ngFor` by referencing the index itself as it increments automatically. If he had posted a more complex problem there'll be another answer merely that depends on what he wants. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **ngModel** to sync the data between the object and input element

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of arraytoDispaly;">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="elm.inputValue" /> {{elm.inputValue}}
</div>
```